Adjusting mouse coordinates in on_click event
I`m trying to create a game with a map, that is dragable with the mouse and has some clickable "buildings" on it.
So I know I need to add the camera viewport lower left corner coordinates to the mouse position, to get the world and screen coordinates adjusted.
But i don´t know how to do this, like how to manipulate the mouse coordinates in the on_click / UIMouseEvent  and how to constantly add  adjustment to the current mouse position to cover hover events as well.

ok found the solution meself:
I created a class inheriting from the arcade.gui.UIManager
class UIManagerPlus(arcade.gui.UIManager):
    def __init__(self, window: arcade.Window | None = None):
        super().__init__(window)
        self.cam_lower_left_x = 0
        self.cam_lower_left_y = 0

    def adjust_mouse_coordinates(self, x, y):
        return (x + self.cam_lower_left_x), (y + self.cam_lower_left_y)

class MyView(arcade.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.manager = UIManagerPlus()
        self.camera = arcade.Camera2D()
        ...

    def on_update(self):
        self.manager.cam_lower_left_x = self.camera.bottom_left.x
        self.manager.cam_lower_left_y = self.camera.bottom_left.y

Im using arcade 3.0.0.dev29, where the new Camera2D is implemented

You can match coordinates between minimap/map using math proportion. Simple example:
import arcade

MINIMAP_SIZE = 200
MINIMAP_SCALE = 4


class MiniMap(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(width=MINIMAP_SIZE*MINIMAP_SCALE, height=MINIMAP_SIZE*MINIMAP_SCALE)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        arcade.draw_rectangle_filled(MINIMAP_SIZE/2, MINIMAP_SIZE/2, MINIMAP_SIZE, MINIMAP_SIZE, color=arcade.color.RED)
        arcade.draw_point(self.x*MINIMAP_SCALE, self.y*MINIMAP_SCALE, arcade.color.WHITE, 10)

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, delta_x, delta_y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


MiniMap()
arcade.run()


